# In what folder should I put my extension methods in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, extension-methods

Like the title said, In what folder should I put my extension methods in ASP.Net MVC?

What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 35):

I don't believe that there is a standard best practice to follow, but I usually do one of two things:

- For smaller projects, I'll simply create an "Extensions" folder, and add the various extension classes to there.
- For larger solutions, I'll have a separate project named something like *ProjectName.Extensions*, and within that project, I will have a folder structure that mirrors the namespaces of the classes I'm extending.  For example:

`ProjectName.Extensions/System/StringExtensions.cs` `ProjectName.Extensions/System.Web/HttpContextExtensions.cs`
`ProjectName.Extensions/System.Xml/XmlWriterExtensions.cs`

And so on...

Regardless of which approach I take, in both cases I'll name the class `ClassNameExtensions.cs` (e.g., StringExtensions.cs, ListExtensions.cs, etc.).

Comment: I like the answer for the second suggestion to use namespaces. I have always been in doubt how to 'accommodate' the extension methods. So far I have called them as 'helper's, for example StringHelper.cs. All kind of 'helpers' are a code smell in the OO world so I like your way more.